# Jasmine test case on ng-repeat function to calculate total

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I need to write a test case on a function which calculates total for a shopping cart.

My Html code

```
<table> 
    <tr ng-repeat = "x in countrynames">
        <td>{{x.Goods}}</td>
        <td>{{x.City}}</td>
        <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
        <td>{{x.count}}</td>
        <td>{{x.quantity}}</td>
        <td>Total : {{ x.total }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller file

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

     $http.get("./country.json").then(function(response) {
        $scope.countrynames = response.data.records;
        $scope.getTotal();
    });

    $scope.getTotal = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.countrynames.length; i++){
            var product = $scope.countrynames[i];
            product.total = (product.quantity * product.count);

        } 
        return total;
    }

});
```

Need help to write test case on getTotal function, I am new to jasmine :)
The function is simple multipication logic for quantity and count of products.

Thank you

Comment: it('should display four thumbnails on the nexus-s page', function() {
      var item = element.all(by.repeater('x in countrynames')).count();
      expect(item).toBe(4);
    });

Comment: gives error ' ReferenceError: element is not defined'

Comment: Also I want to mock data according to the logic in getTotal rather than count :)

Comment: what u want TDD  or E2E testing ?

Comment: Hello RIYAJ I am looking for E2E testing.

Comment: Just to update I have karma jasmine and karma coverage alongwith gulp installed....I want to mock simple multiplication logic written in my getTotal function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example I am not seeing where your getTotal function is actually used?

Anyhow, this is just one way that you could test the getTotal function:

```
describe('myCtrl', function () {
var scope, ctrl;

// Load the myApp module, which contains the controller
beforeEach(module('myApp'))

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('myCtrl', {$scope: scope});
}));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    backend = $httpBackend;
}));

it('Test that total matched expected', function () {
    backend.expect("GET", "./country.json").
        respond(200,
        [{
            // insert a sample of your country.json here.
        }]
    );
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.getTotal()).toBe(4);  // change 4 to be the number of results you expected.
});
```